# MVC6 PostAuthentication Using Cookie

Tags: session-cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for a way to call a function onPostAuthenticate after a cookie login.

I tried for searching SignInAsync override, Or in startup.cs to have a delegate or lambda to call my own class/function.

It will be great if any event/delegates in my login controller constructor i can wire.

```
public HomeController(UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, AddressbookAppContext AddressbookDb)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;

        //_signInManager.SignInAsync ();
        this.AddressbookDb = AddressbookDb;
    }
```

Comment: I managed to get the place close to OnPostAuthenticate using CookieAuthenticationNotifications in startup.cs. However I would like to know can I use DbContext to query the database for fetching more information from db?

Answer (score 1):

After a long struggle. I managed to find a place to get the Post Login to populate the records from db to user.

The place to look for is CookieAuthenticationNotifications in CookieAuthenticationOptions. There is a OnValidatePrincipal which gets called after the login is finished. The code itself is self explanatory.

```
  services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.Notifications = new CookieAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = async (context) =>
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        if (context.Principal.Identity != null && context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        { 

                            SecurityManager SecMan = new SecurityManager(new AddressbookAppContext(Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"))); 
                            SessionHelper<ContextUser>.Put(context.HttpContext, "LoggedInUser", 
                                SecMan.FetchContextUser(context.Principal.Identity.Name));

                            // context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("iBoltzTest", "test");
                        }
                        else //UnAuthorized

                        {

                            //Your code is here

                        }

                    });
                }
            };
            opt.LoginPath = PathString.FromUriComponent("/Home/Login");
        });
```